# Samatha while studying

Tags: meditation, meditation-recommendation, samatha, meditation-samatha

I heard about the practice of concentration. But I work 13 hours per day doing coding. How can I meditate while studying, thinking really deep?

I can focus on one static object, but not reading (coding) documentation, write code remaining in one state of completely self center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Higher levels of concentration is not possible while the mind is active but you can have some level of non-exclusive focus on like the breath or bodily sensations while working. You need to develop [initial and sustained focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitarka-vic%C4%81ra) on a chosen object.

Comment: this could partially reply https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/31772/is-mindfulness-the-opposite-of-multitasking so that studying  code, or solve a programming problem becomes a multitasking activity by default, and I should focus to act for priority